# ObjectMapper behaving weirdly when mapping "is" prefixed Boolean field

Tags: java, lombok, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I have a Boolean field in the request body of an API, named "isSafe". This field is mapped to my Pojo class using ObjectMapper.

If I send "safe" in the request then it fails and I get this error Unrecognized field "safe". But this same request starts getting passed after sometime.

My application is deployed on cloud and I have multiple pods running. After any deployment/restarts of the application, this request fails (which is expected), but after 1-2 hour, one-by-one pods starts giving success response. Eventually, all the requests start getting successful.

Note: I am aware of the conflicts created by Jackson with "is" prefix name field. But in my case, request starts getting successful after a period of time. This is weird.

My question is that why initially after server restart mapper throws error and after some time doesn't throw error even if I pass "safe" field.

Pojo Class field ( I am using @Data for getter and setter):

```
private Boolean isSafe;
```

ObjectMapper bean:

```
new ObjectMapper()
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
        .registerModules(new JavaTimeModule(), new Jdk8Module());
```

Initial Analysis: If I add @JsonIgnoreProperties in my Pojo class where this field is defined then it works as expected ("safe" field is ignored). But without this, it behaves in a weird way.

Comment: This is a very old bug. @Hantsy's solution will work

Comment: Actually, I need to understand why "safe" is getting mapped to "isSafe" after sometime of the server restart? 
In the beginning of server restart it throws error which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Add JsonProperty to your pojo to specify the field named mapped in JSON string.

```java
class YourPoJo{

   @JsonProperty("isSafe")
   private boolean safe;
}
```

Then you can use `isSafe` in the request body.

Comment: Yes, this works. But my question is why the object mapper throws error with "safe" at first, but then after some time it starts accepting "safe". Can you please help on this.

Comment: Use `boolean` to replace `Boolean`, it will be mapped as `isSafe()` (as getter) I think.